# SQL Server : violation of primary key constraint cannot insert duplicate key

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert the duplicate values into the table which has foreign key constraint but my real challenge is to catch the caused value into the catch block and return it as output parameter.

So could you all please let me know if its possible to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us more detail on how you insert the data. In a procedure? through application? in a loop? in trigger? ....

Comment: In a procedure using while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRY 
insert into primary_keyed_table 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  select error_message()
  select REPLACE (error_message(),'Violation of primary key.....','')
END CATCH
```

Comment: Try this way and use replace to remove the unwanted part from the error message. It will show the possible duplicates in the error message . Capture the duplicate.